# Heroku wont connect to my django database

Tags: django, heroku, heroku-postgres, django-database, heroku-api

my database is the default sqlite3 database, I tried with multiple projects but Heroku won't connect to the database, hope u guys will help me
I'm new to Heroku i don't know if I'm missing something

these are my settings setup for Heroku, I have no static files

```
import django_heroku
import dj_database_url

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

DATABASES = {
    'default': dj_database_url.config()
}

django_heroku.settings(locals())
```

Answer (score 1):

A pretty typical use of Django on Heroku involves having Postgres SQL for your database. Your local development and test data will use SQLite but when you publish your site and run migrations the database that's configured at Heroku will be Postgres SQL. This does not push your local database's data to production.

The production database will have the same tables as your local database but will be empty. If you have data locally you'd like to get into that you can create scripts or use Django import / export to load data.

Heroku's Getting Started with python/Django walkthrough is worth going through to learn about provisioning a database.

Answer (score 1):

SQLite is a database on the disk, it is very useful for development purposes, however, services like Heroku expect your server-side code to be stateless, which as a consequence does not really allow for databases such as SQLite. As Heroku's dynos don't have a filesystem that persists across deploys, a file-based database like SQLite3 isn't going to be suitable.

I guess you could make it work (provided you find a place on Heroku's disk where to put your SQLite DB) but you would constantly lose your database's content every time you redeploy.

Heroku does have a [Postgres](https://www.heroku.com/postgres) Offering. However, that will suit - with a free tier and a basic $9/month tier that are good for hobby/small projects. The biggest benefit over SQLite is that you get backups that you wouldn't get otherwise (plus all the other Postgres features).

There's a guide to updating your settings.py to use Postgres here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-django#django-settings